# Why is Pandas-API-on-Spark's apply on groups a way slower than pyspark API?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I'm having strange performance results when comparing the two APIs in pyspark 3.2.1 that provide ability to run pandas UDF on grouped results of Spark Dataframe:

- [df.groupBy().applyInPandas()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html?highlight=applyinpandas#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas)
- [ps_df.groupby().apply() - a new way of apply introduced in Pandas-API-on-Spark AKA Koalas](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html)

First I run the following input generator code in local spark mode (Spark 3.2.1):

```
import pyspark.sql.types as types
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.pandas as ps

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", True) \
    .getOrCreate()

ps.set_option("compute.default_index_type", "distributed")

spark.range(1000000).withColumn('group', (col('id') / 10).cast('int')) \
    .write.parquet('/tmp/sample_input', mode='overwrite')
```

Then I test the `applyInPandas`:

```
def getsum(pdf):
    pdf['sum_in_group'] = pdf['id'].sum()
    return pdf

df = spark.read.parquet(f'/tmp/sample_input')
output_schema = types.StructType(
    df.schema.fields + [types.StructField('sum_in_group', types.FloatType())]
)
df.groupBy('group').applyInPandas(getsum, schema=output_schema) \
    .write.parquet('/tmp/schematest', mode='overwrite')
```

And the code executes **under 30 seconds** (on i7-9750H CPU)

Then, I try the new API and - while I really appreciate how nice the code looks like:

```
def getsum(pdf) -> ps.DataFrame["id": int, "group": int, "sum_in_group": int]:
    pdf['sum_in_group'] = pdf['id'].sum()
    return pdf

df = ps.read_parquet(f'/tmp/sample_input')
df.groupby('group').apply(getsum) \
    .to_parquet('/tmp/schematest', mode='overwrite')
```

... every time the execution time is **at least 1m 40s** on the same CPU, so **more than 3x slower** for this simple operation.

I am aware that adding `sum_in_group` can be done way more efficient with no panadas involvement, but this is just to provide a small minimal example. Any other operations is also at least 3 times slower.

Do you know what would be the reason to this slowdown? Maybe I'm lacking some context parameter that would make these execute in the similar time?

Comment: We encountered the same thing when doing benchmarks for our project (Fugue) [here](https://fugue-tutorials.readthedocs.io/tutorials/appendix/fugue_not_pandas.html). Just look at the images on that page. You will notice PySpark Pandas is consistently slow across the board.

I personally think this has to do with the index that they add on top of the Spark DataFrame for compatibility with the Pandas API. The index adds a lot of overhead in the distributed setting because it essentially keeps a global order, which is often unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks @kvnkho, your benchmark results are super useful. I also have a gut feeling that it's somehow related with index they on the top of Spark DF. However, if schema is set, the index should not be retained (see: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.1/python/pyspark/pandas/groupby.py#L1303). I'm forcing `distributed` index that should be almost instant, as it's based on `monotonically_increasing_id()` - unfortunately, the Spark execution plans are truncated, so it's hard to debug...

Comment: Using the `distributed` index already seems very good to me. I have no ideas what else you can tune. Totally understand what you are saying, it is pretty confusing that the performance gap is that big.